# Join 2 datasets that have different levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to join two dataframes, but one of them is multi-indexed like so:

[Multi-level dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUvgL.png)

The other dataframe is much simpler:

[Basic dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z4BB.png)

How can I join these two dataframes while still preserving the multi-level structure of the first dataframe?

This is what I'm getting at the moment:

[image: Only one level for the merged dataframe]

Comment: Kindly provide the code to replicate your dataframes and the output you expect. Regards.

Comment: My code is a little hard to follow because I have a few things going on in the back-end, but this is what I have:

date_OAS = pd.DataFrame(date_getter(new_dfs), columns = ['-1W', 'ME', 'QE', 'YE']) <br/>

s = date_OAS.stack() <br/>

date_OAS = pd.DataFrame([*s], s.index, columns=['OAS to Treasury (bp)', 'Change in OAS to Today (bp)']).stack().unstack([1, 2]) <br/>


total_info = pd.concat([df_info, date_OAS], axis = 1, join = 'inner') <br/>

Answer (score 0):

There is several solution to your problem. I think you can use concat or merge from panda library.
I hope it will help you:

```
import panda as pd

dataframe1 = (pd.read_csv('test1.csv', sep=';', header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True))
dataframe2 = (pd.read_csv('test2.csv', sep=';', header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True))

dataframe3 = pd.concat([dataframe1, dataframe2], axis=1, join='inner') # using concat
dataframe4 = pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, left_index=True, right_index=True) # using merge

#export to csv
dataframe3.to_csv('test3.csv', sep=';', header=True, index=True)
dataframe4.to_csv('test4.csv', sep=';', header=True, index=True)
```

What do you think about this ?

Comment: I still get the result I posted above sadly. I'd like it so that the merged dataframe would preserve the multi-level column index of the first dataframe